# Compilation error "[ReflectionException] Class does not exist" - Magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, compilation

Yesterday I run the command:

```
sudo -u magento bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

And I've got a strange error, the site seems to be running 100% but before Yesterday I didn't use to get any error during compilation.

Is there any known issue about that? Magento version 2.0.7.

See image below:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible there is a permissions problem ?

Comment: Before to run the di:compile I made sure that the permissions and file ownership are right.

Comment: Looks like class ' ' (a whitespace) is defined somewhere (or something interpreted as a whitespace). Is it possible for you to review recent changes in di.xml files or calls to object manager, of any? Or run the command with -vvv , identify where it comes from and see if there is something suspicious there (or debug if possible)

Answer (score -2):

If it is not too late, you may try cli with -vvv params.

```
sudo -u magento bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
```

Comment: What is use of -vvv parameter?

Comment: This will give a Stack Trace which could give a hint where exactly the error is.